# PHP Class Warning

Tags: php, wordpress, class

Below is a snippet from our functions.php file. Our WP Theme is built using Classes and I'm getting several warnings from our PHP IDE PHPStorm that state:

```
1. Referenced field is not found in subject class.
```

The warnings are applied to the arguments direction after `$this->`, and on the paths, i.e., `class-tgm-plugin-activation.php`, we are getting a `"Include expression is not resolved" warning"`.

I believe this issue has to do with the way we are defining and calling our variables between the functions. Any help would be appreciated in pointing us in the right direction. Thanks.

Full close snippet here:

```
// Setup SG Class
class myclassname {

// Define static variables for use in class files
static $sg_theme_version = NULL;
static $sg_theme_name = NULL;
static $sg_theme_slug = NULL;
static $sg_default_loop_thumbnail = NULL;
static $sg_avatar = NULL;
static $sg_comment_avatar = NULL;
static $sg_author_avatar = NULL;

public static function get_instance() {
    static $instance = null;

    if ($instance === null) {
        $instance = new self();
        $instance->setup_public_variables();
        $instance->setup_static_variables();
        $instance->setup_files();
        $instance->setup_hooks();
    }
}

protected function __construct() {
    // Do nothing here
}

static function setup_static_variables() {
    if ( is_null(self::$sg_theme_version) ) {
        self::$sg_theme_version          = '1.0.0';
        self::$sg_theme_name             = 'mytheme';
        self::$sg_theme_slug             = 'myslug';
        self::$sg_default_loop_thumbnail = 'https://cdn.mysite.com/wp/sg/';
        self::$sg_avatar                 = '115';
        self::$sg_comment_avatar         = '180';
        self::$sg_author_avatar          = '140';
    }
}

public function setup_public_variables() {
    $this->**sg_theme_version** = '1.0.0';
    $this->**sg_theme_name** = 'mytheme';
    $this->**sg_theme_slug** = 'myslug';

    // Used for Genesis Framework
    define('CHILD_THEME_NAME', $this->**sg_theme_name**);

    if (defined('CHILD_THEME_NAME')) {
        $this->**directory_url** = trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory_uri());
        $this->**directory_path** = trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory());
    } else {
        $this->**directory_url** = trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri());
        $this->directory_path = trailingslashit(get_template_directory());
    }

    $this->includes_url = trailingslashit($this->directory_url . 'includes');
    $this->includes_path = trailingslashit($this->directory_path . 'includes');

    $this->libraries_url = trailingslashit($this->includes_url . 'libraries');
    $this->libraries_path = trailingslashit($this->includes_path . 'libraries');

    $this->integrations_url = trailingslashit($this->includes_url . 'integrations');
    $this->integrations_path = trailingslashit($this->includes_path . 'integrations');

    $this->admin_url = trailingslashit($this->includes_url . 'admin');
    $this->admin_path = trailingslashit($this->includes_path . 'admin');
}

public function setup_files() {

    # Integrations
    require_once($this->integrations_path . 'genesis.php');
    require_once($this->libraries_path . 'class-tgm-plugin-activation.php');
    require_once($this->includes_path . 'sg-functions.php');
    require_once($this->includes_path . 'sg-email.php');

}

public function setup_hooks() {
    add_action('after_switch_theme', array($this, 'activation'));
    add_action('switch_theme', array($this, 'deactivation'));

    add_action('tgmpa_register', array($this, 'setup_plugins'));
    add_action('genesis_setup', array($this, 'setup_theme'));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the warning messages that the log file is reporting?

Comment: It says, "Referenced field is not found in subject class". That Warning is showing up on several lines in the above snippet presumably due to the same core issue, i.e., we're somehow not defining our variables corrections in the Class.

Comment: Probably at the assigments to `*_url` and `*_path`? Those variables are not defined in the class. Both can be found in `setup_public_variables()` and `setup_files()`.

Comment: All variables defined within the public function setup_public_variables() block have the warning, and all variables defined in the public function setup_files() block. The warnings are applied to the arguments direction after "$this->", and on the paths, we are getting a ""Include expression is not resolved" warning".